# Cakephp 3 url parameter default

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I would like to add into all my link into my site the language parameter.

Something like:

```
http://www.example.com/en/home
```

This is my routes.php file:

```
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

Router::defaultRouteClass('Route');

Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
    if (isset($request->params['language']) && !isset($params['language'])) {
        $params['language'] = $request->params['language'];
    }
    else{
        $params['language'] = 'en';
    }
    return $params;
});

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $lang = 'en|it|fr';

    $routes->connect('/', ['language' => 'en', 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index', 'index']);

    $routes->connect(
        '/:language/:controller',
        ['action' => 'index'],
        ['language' => $lang]
    );

    $routes->connect(
        '/:language/:controller/:action',
        ['language' => $lang]
    );

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});

Plugin::routes();
```

The problem is:

- when I write this url: `http://example.com/admins` it becomes `http://example.com/en/admins/index` **correctly**
- when I write this url: `http://example.com/admins/index` it becomes `http://example.com/admins/index` **NOT correctly**

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried using prefix routing? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: "_when I write ... it becomes ..._" What does "_writing"_ in this context mean, and what is "_it_"?

Comment: if I write into the url bar into the browser it means @ndm

Comment: I have read It but I can't do It, or not understand how to do It, can you please make an example? @Makville

Comment: That's only half the answer... It's still unclear what the "_it_" in "_it becomes_" is?

Comment: the routing system get the url and edit It. Because I would like that in every link created the lang is always into the url @ndm

Comment: You're not getting my point. What I'm asking for, is where exactly what exactly changes? For sure the URL in the browser will not suddenly change unless you're doing a redirect. So what is "it", where does "it" change? Are you referring to generated URLs, for example via `Router::url()` or `HtmlHelper::link()`? If so, please show an example of the affected code.

Comment: @Alessandro. I want to try to see if i understand the problem you are describing. Here goes: You essentially need a way to echo out the appropriate url from the Html->link method call so that it contains the appropriate language key or you want the user to type an address and cakephp redirects them to the appropriate page with the language key showing in the browser automatically. Which are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Makville I don't want to specify in every url the language but I would like that the system prefix language before every url